# Hibernate: mapping nested objects -EDITED-

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

For example, I have the following tables:

USER:

| USERID | USERNAME | USERTYPEID |

USERTYPE:

| USERTYPEID | USERTYPENAME |

So clearly USERTYPEID is a foreign key that a user use to refer to usertype. The JAVA implementation is as such:

I have a class User and a class UserType, where looks like:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private UserType ut;
    ....
}

public class UserType {
    ...
}
```

In the User.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.pretech.User" table="User">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="UserID">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So my questions follows:

1) what should I put to map the `UserType` here and indicate UserType as foreign key?

2) In the case of User includes a list of `UserType` (may not conceptually true but just want to use as an example), such as:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private List<UserType> uts;
}
```

what shoud I do about the hibernate mapping?

**EDIT:**
Added explanation about foreign key stuff.

Comment: If both `user` and `user_type` are two different tables, you can use a straight forward one to many mapping.

Comment: @Rp- They are two different tables, and how would hibernate know that the usertypeId in user table is a foreign key refering to usertype table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many examples available in net for your example, you can also check the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-unidirectional-12m):

For example if you want to have a `User` entity with a set of `UserType's` then you can use `one-to-many` relationship and the mapping file will be:

```
<class name="User">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="uts">
        <key column="userId" 
            not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="UserType"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="UserType">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
</class>
```

And [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-indexed) is another example from the documentation that uses annotations and List instead of Set:

Comment: Could you please explain how would hibernate know that the usertypeId in user table is a foreign key refering to usertype table?

Comment: In my example, as per mapping the `UserType` table will have the foreign key with name `userId` that references to `User` table. The line `<key column="userId" not-null="true"/>` represents the foreign key. I think it is better you go through the document and you will learn hibernate clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be OneToOne or OneToMany depending on UserType is a single reference or multiple (collection list).
Search on Google and you will get numerous tutorials with both  xml based and annotations based

Comment: Could you please explain how would hibernate know that the usertypeId in user table is a foreign key refering to usertype table?